# Find parameters inside of URL and display them

Tags: jquery, regex, url, parameters

Currently I have a link such as *www.fakelink.com/fake/?* that will add on two numbers based on a submit button. So a link could look like *www.fakelink.com/fake/?/85/74/*

I want to grab the parameters (*85* and *74* in this example) and then grab them and place them into variables like:

```
var parm1 = parm1value
var parm2 = parm2value
```

Currently using jQuery to try and achieve this. I've been racking my brain all night trying to come up with a solution. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: No jQuery required here, you need to `split` the URL string by `?` and then by `/` to get the values in an array.

Comment: `location.search.split('/')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html):

```
var r = /^www.fakelink.com\/fake\/[^\/]\/(\d+)\/(\d+)/;
var s = 'www.fakelink.com/fake/foo/85/74/';
var m = s.match(r);

var parm1 = m[1]; // 85
var parm2 = m[2]; // 74
```